# Error while uploading shapefile to Google Earth Engine

Tags: qgis, shapefile, google-earth-engine

I tried loading a shapefile that I made in QGIS to the code editor (Assets). In the select file menu I selected the shp, shx, prj, dbf. The files are in WGS 84 projection. Every time I try to upload I get 2 kinds of error:

1- Error: `Unable to transform edge (3877983.178902, 3731126.448814 to 3877983.180887, 3731126.448640) from GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", DATUM["D_WGS_1984", SPHEROID["WGS_1984", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]], PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], AXIS["Longitude", EAST], AXIS["Latitude", NORTH]] PLANAR to EPSG:4326.`

2- Error: `Unable to transform edge (3877983.178902, 3731126.448814 to 3877983.180887, 3731126.448640) from EPSG:4326 PLANAR to EPSG:4326.`

I tried re projecting the files but it didn't help. How do i solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your projection (WGS84 EPSG:4326) is incorrect, the coordinates look to be in metres, they're definitely not decimal degrees.

You haven't re-projected your data, you have assigned an incorrect projection definition.

You need to [assign the correct projection](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#assign-projection).

The correct projection could be anything, but if you digitised off a basemap, it may be [WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857).